# Вывод экранированных последовательностей (escape sequences) юникода вместо символов

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, python-2.x, psycopg2

Запускаю такую программу:

```
import psycopg2
connect = psycopg2.connect(dbname='this_db', user='postgres',
                        password='newPassword', host='localhost')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM the_table;")
print(cur.fetchall())
```

Выводит это:

```
[('\xd0\x90\xd0\x91', '\xd0\x92\xd0\x93')]
```

В моей таблице нет такого. Пишу это в консоль:

```
SELECT * FROM the_table;
```

Вот что выводит:

```
 txt1 | txt2
------+------
 АБ   | ВГ
(1 row)
```

Если к строке '\xd0\x90\xd0\x91' дописать `.decode('utf-8')`, то все работает.
То есть:

```
'\xd0\x90\xd0\x91'.decode('utf-8')
```

Выводит нужный результат.

Что надо справить, чтобы выводило `[('АБ', 'ВГ')]` вместо `[('\xd0\x90\xd0\x91', '\xd0\x92\xd0\x93')]` и не дописывать везде `.decode('utf-8')`?

PS:
Попытался написать так:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras
import psycopg2.extensions

psycopg2.extensions.register_type(psycopg2.extensions.UNICODE)
psycopg2.extensions.register_type(psycopg2.extensions.UNICODEARRAY)

conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='this_db', user='postgres',
                        password='newPassword', host='localhost')

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM t0;")
print(cur.fetchall())

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Но выводит такое:

```
[(u'\u0410\u0411', u'\u0412\u0413'), (u'\u0410\u0411', u'\u0412\u0413'), (u'\u0410\u0411', u'\u0412\u0413')]
```

Comment: Вы используете Python 2.x?

Comment: @MaxU, python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Решение для Python 2.x](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#unicode-handling):

> **Note** In Python 2, if you want to uniformly receive all your database input in Unicode, you can register the related typecasters
>   globally as soon as Psycopg is imported:
>
> ```
> import psycopg2.extensions
> psycopg2.extensions.register_type(psycopg2.extensions.UNICODE)
> psycopg2.extensions.register_type(psycopg2.extensions.UNICODEARRAY)
> ```
>
> and forget about this story.

Comment: Тогда выводит такое: [(u'\u0410\u0411', u'\u0412\u0413'), (u'\u0410\u0411', u'\u0412\u0413'), (u'\u0410\u0411', u'\u0412\u0413')]

Comment: А если вывести не массив а просто элемент `print(cursor.fetchall()[0][0]);` то выводит правильно

Comment: @Vlad, это «такое» и есть UTF-8. Попробуйте вывести эти строки при помощи print()

Comment: ,как я и написал выше, если выводить по одному элементу - то все верно. Но как сделать чтобы список (массив) выводился правильно?

Comment: @Vlad, почитайте о работе с Unicode в Python 2.x или переходите на Python 3.x

Comment: У меня вроде и так python 3 (ведь в python 3 print() со скобками). А как понять что я не на Python 3 и перейти на него?

Comment: Если запустить программу так `python3 prog.py`, то выведет `import psycopg2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'`. Сейчас попытаюсь разобраться

Comment: Да на python3 все заработало, спасибо